# TypeError: execute_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch'

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, psycopg2, flask-marshmallow

I am having an issue with creating an entry into a many-to-many postgresql db table with Flask, Flask-sqlalchemy, and flask-marshmallow. Below are my model setups.

```
role_permissions = db.Table(
    'role_permissions',
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
         'roles.id', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='CASCADE')),
    db.Column('permission_id', db.Integer,
          db.ForeignKey('op_permission.id', ondelete='RESTRICT', onupdate='CASCADE')))
```

Here are the individual Tables: Role and Permission

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(),
                           server_onupdate=db.func.now())

    permissions = db.relationship(
        "Permission", secondary=role_permissions, backref=db.backref('roles', lazy='joined'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role {}>'.format(self.name)

    def has_id(self, id: int) -> bool:
        if Role.query.filter_by(id=id).count():
            return True
        return False

    def has_name(self, name: str) -> bool:
        if Role.query.filter_by(name=name).count():
            return True
        return False
```

```
class Permission(db.Model):
    """
    Model for permission such as GetWallet
    a combination of Action and Service
    """
    __tablename__ = 'op_permission'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    service_id = db.Column(db.Integer(),
                           db.ForeignKey('op_service.id', ondelete='CASCADE'),
                           nullable=True)
    service = db.relationship(Service)

    action = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

And now when I am trying to add a set of permissions to a role (I already have an admin role for instance) using this marshmallow schema and the view below

```
class RolePermissionsAPIView(FlaskView):
    route_base = 'iam/roles/<id>/permissions'

    """ Assign permissions to roles """

    def post(self, id, **kwargs):
        try:
            role = Role.query.filter_by(id=id).first_or_404()

            post_data = request.get_json()
            role_perm = RolePermissionsCreateSchema(partial=True).load(post_data)

            db.session.add(role_perm)
            db.session.commit()

            # also tried this
            #role.permissions.append(role_perm.permissions)
            #db.session.add(role)
            #db.session.commit()

            return jsonify(data=RoleSchema().dump(role), status=True), 201
        except NotFound:
            raise CustomException(
                message="Role does not exist", status_code=400)
        except marshmallow.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
            raise CustomException(
                message=dict(errors=e.messages), status_code=400)
```

And the schema for deserialization, I want to pass in a list of existing permission ids to append to a role at once.

```
class RolePermissionsCreateSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    permissions = fields.Pluck('PermissionListSchema', 'id', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Role
```

Here is the 422 Unprocessable entity error I'm getting when I pass in this data.

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "permissions": [1, 2]
}
```

I have googled to no avail. could it be with psycopg2?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_classful.py", line 268, in proxy
    response = view(**request.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_classful.py", line 239, in inner
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/users/api/v2/roles.py", line 82, in post
    db.session.commit()
  File "<string>", line 2, in commit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1428, in commit
    self._transaction.commit(_to_root=self.future)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 829, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 808, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3340, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3480, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 72, in __exit__
    with_traceback=exc_tb,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3440, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 456, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 579, in execute
    self.dependency_processor.process_saves(uow, states)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 1183, in process_saves
    uowcommit, secondary_insert, secondary_update, secondary_delete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/dependency.py", line 1245, in _run_crud
    connection.execute(statement, secondary_insert)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1286, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 326, in _execute_on_connection
    self, multiparams, params, execution_options
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1488, in _execute_clauseelement
    cache_hit=cache_hit,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1843, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2027, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1780, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 957, in do_executemany
    **kwargs
TypeError: execute_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetch'
```

Would appreciate any assistance.